# StaleElement after going back from a page in a loop

Tags: java, selenium, loops

This is the code presently. I receive a StaleElement Exception as I have gone back. But I need to get the `links` variable repopulated again and loop further. Any way of doing it within the loop or any other pointers?

```
List<WebElement> links = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions
        .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("a.c-showurl.c-color-gray")));
for (WebElement link : links) {
    position++;
    actualDomain = link.getText().trim();
    System.out.println("actualDomain: " + actualDomain);
    for (KwMetrics kwm : kwmList) {
        targetDomain = kwm.getTargetDomain();
        if (actualDomain.contains("http://" + targetDomain)
                || actualDomain.contains("https://" + targetDomain)
                || actualDomain.contains("." + targetDomain)) {
            link.click();
            driver.navigate().back();
            System.out.println("Got back to the previous page...");
            
            // The issue is here (Stale Element)
            // do something using the link from for loop
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the List to be updated which is at the beginning of the code.

`List<WebElement> links = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("a.c-showurl.c-color-gray")));`

Comment: If it's an a tag just collect all the href values and navigate to the href value. Instead of clicking.

Comment: But I still have to get back to the previous page!! The click is a must anyway.

Comment: If that is the case the answer currently up provides the solution. Also don't use exclamation.

Answer (score 0):

The element references will be get's updated each time you perform some operations like click, refresh, back, or forward in the browser. So, selenium can't access the old element references as part of a loop, so the solution is to get the element references (elements within the loop) or get the number of elements matching with your criteria and get that particular index item within the loop each time either by using the XPATH index `//xpath[index` or get all elements and then use the index like `driver.findElements().get(index)`

Comment: please check the edit.. I need to refresh the list which over which the loop iterates.